# Web API methods never get routed to

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I've played with web api a bit before, and I always seem to run into the same problem where my methods do not get routed to.

My application has that application insights package and so I can see that it captures the requests I make - by looking at the requests line above my method signature, but they never actually execute and App Insights reports a failed request.

Here is my WebApiConfig

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
;
```

Here is my simple controller and method

```
public class ExampleController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("Test")]
    public IHttpActionResult Test()
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

This is part of an MVC application, so when I launch the project, the Home/Index view is displayed in my browser. I then go to postman and create a new Get request pointing at

```
http://localhost:port/api/Example/Test
```

But this results in a 404.

I must be doing something wrong as I always run into this

Comment: Is this in OWIN? If so, could we see your Startup.cs? If not, could we see your Global.asax's `Application_Start` method?

Comment: Thank you Jonathan - my global.asax.cs file was missing a GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

Comment: For future visitors with Web API route problems, I strongly recommend using the free [Web API Debugger](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/debugging-asp-net-web-api-with-route-debugger/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default mapping for WebAPI does not include the action as part of the route, as it, by default, expects the controller to be the main identifier for a resource and the GET/POST/PUT/DELETE verb to define which operation is run.

So, even though you are manually specifying the ActionName of "Test", there's nothing in the default handler to pattern match against it.

You could adjust your default mapping to include actions, like so:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
;
```

However, you might find you prefer attribute routing (I know I do), which you could apply to your controller like this:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Example")]
public class ExampleController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Test")]
    public IHttpActionResult Test()
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

To enable attribute routing, you will need to add the following to your startup configuration:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

Comment: I have copied your routeprefix example and still encounter the same issue. When you use routeprefix, do we need to remove the route specified in webapiconfig?

Comment: @andrewb Sorry, you need to add `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` to your WebApiConfig above the MapHttpRoute call. I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: @andrewb Something else must be going on in your configuration/environment. Dropping that controller into a fresh Web API 2 template project works as expected (VS 2017).

Comment: I just did that too and it works, so I presume the project is off in some way? Any idea what it could be? I have the required references to inherit from ApiController

Comment: @andrewb Without seeing more of your configuration and application startup I cannot say.